# Modify code construct to allow xsl:if

Tags: 2010, xslt

In the snippet below, I want to be able to change the value in the first href= to a different WP form based on another value in the list.
I want to embed the code in conditional statements to test for values.
The Management Appraisal...  is defined in Manage Connections.
I want to override the Connection value.

```
</tr><tr><td class="style6" style="width: 8%">Form ID<a href="{@Tier_Appraisal_URL}"></a></td><td><a href="Management Appraisal copy - Emp.aspx"><xsl:value-of select="@Tier_Appraisal_URL.desc" /></a></td></tr>
```

I think it should be simple but I cant come up with correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do conditional logic in xslt/dvwps, `xsl:choose` and `xsl:if`. They operate in similar ways but can give you different results. `xsl:if` only happens when the test evaluates to true, `xsl:choose` will always return something. Typical usages:

You are guaranteed to get one of these in the markup

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@Field = 'A'">
        Foo
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="@Field = 'B'">
        Bar
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        Baz
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

This will onlybe output if Field equals A, but if Field equals B it gets skipped

```
<xsl:if test="@Field = 'A'">Foo</xsl:if>
```